# How to to math operation in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates

I am writing a web app in Django where a user can vote a post, from 1 to 5 (using stars), when I want to display the stars I have to decide how many of them have to be yellow and how many not.
I save the feedback in this model:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    stars = models.IntegerField(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 6)], blank=False)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the problem is in the template, because I would like to do something like this, but i don't know how and if it is a good choice:

```
        {% for _ in art.stars %}
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for _ in (5-art.stars) %}
            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `check` class will give yellow color? right?

Answer (score 1):

First we will pass range from `views.py`:

```
return render(request, 'template_name', {'art': art, 'range': range(1, 6),})
```

You can do sthg like this:

```
{% for index in range %}
    <span class="fa fa-star {% if index <= art.stars %}checked{% endif %}"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you don't want to pass range in `views`, you can use [`make_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#make-list) in template.